# Windows 8: Problems installing VMWare Player

Tags: windows-8, installation, virtual-machine, vmware-player

I'm really going nuts trying to figure out why I can't install VMWare Player on my PC.
I'm running Win8 x64

At first I ran the installer which completes with errors. The error is this:
[image]

I bypassed this by copying the temporary folder created during the installation on my desktop and running the vmwareplayer_x64.msi manually. 
Everything seems to go ok when suddenly I get an "failed to install the hcmon driver" error.

I've tried following these instructions [Installing VMware Player via MSI failed](https://superuser.com/questions/528057/installing-vmware-player-via-msi-failed) (which are on the vmware support site as well) but I can't even find the "non-plug and play drivers" section and on the internet I can't find how to fix this.

I've also tried running the installation as administrator but with no success.

Any suggestion?
Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed it!

Unbeliveably it was Avast. I had to uninstall it, restart my PC and retry installing VMWare and it succeded...
It seems Avast was blocking something... no words.

Thank you anyway

Comment: With VMPlayer 6 the problem has been fixed!

Answer (score 0):

Try running the setup as Administrator. (Right click on it --> Run As Administrator)
Or log on to the Administrator account of your PC and give it a try.

Comment: Sorry, didn't mention it in the question, but I've already tried it with no success.